# XDEBUG remote enable not enabaling

Tags: php, wamp, phpstorm, xdebug

this is my php.ini file for xdebug

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.0\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=C:\wamp64\tmp
```

but according to php info, remote enable is disabled.
If I go into phpstorm under interpreters it recognizes xdebug as the debugger. Let me know if you need more informatoini.

**edit:**
I have tried @lllypa sloution to no avail. I am using windwos 10, firefox, and wamp 3.0.0 64bit with php 7

I reinstalled the server to find this and it is still not working. I can access the localhost, and php scripts work but I can't debug.

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.0\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = on
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="C:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

Comment: If you are running phpstorm on the same PC as you are  running wampserver on, **you are not remote debugging**! Remote debugging is when you are running your IDE on a different PC (IP Address) to the PC running the Server.

Comment: Oh and if you actually are `remote debugging` then you should [read this page located strangely enough **hiding** on the XDEBUG web site](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote) where you will find that there are a number of other parameters that will need to be set to get **remote** debugging working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can understand from the question and a tag, you're using Windows and WAMP, right? WAMP has multiple php.ini files:

1. %Apache folder%\bin\php.ini
2. %PHP folder%\php.ini
3. %PHP folder%\phpForApache.ini

As far as I remember, **phpForApache.ini** is the one that has "final" values, so see if it has xdebug settings. Or to be sure, that you are editing the right *.ini file, use WAMP app (on the taskbar click WAMP icon -> PHP -> php.ini).

Let us know if this helps or give us more details on your system and steps you're doing.

PS. Try adding these parameters to your settings:

```
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
```

And make sure you're running your project on the same host. And if phpstorm has some xdebug configuration - make sure port is the same.

Comment: Only use the wampmanager links to edit _the correct php.ini file_ `wampmanager -> PHP -> php,ini`

Comment: See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727335/xdebug-remote-enable-not-enabaling#comment62931017_37727335)

Comment: This 3 settings at the bottom are all the default values anyway.